# In Log4j2, how to avoid logging messages that contain a certain text?

Tags: logging, log4j2

How can I filter out **Log4j2** messages according to their message content?

For example, I don't want to log Hibernate messages that contain the text: `HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead`. Of course, I can disable all Hibernate deprecation warnings, like this:

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.orm.deprecation" additivity="false" level="ERROR">
    …
</Logger>
```

But then I will get no deprecation warnings at all, and they are usually useful. I want to remove just that one (because there is nothing I can do to fix it, and they are issued by the thousands). Please note this is a Log4j2 question, not a Hibernate question.

Answer (score 5):

Oops, it seems I answered myself, I don't know how I missed this `RegexFilter` :

```
<Logger name="org.hibernate.orm.deprecation" additivity="false" level="WARN">
    <RegexFilter regex=".*HHH90000022.*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    …
</Logger>
```